# How can I get the id from message a bot sent using discord

Tags: python, discord.py, message

I am working with Python discord. And I need to get an id from message. I have a function:

```
async def send_message(user_id, text):
    user = self.client.get_user(user_id)
    await user.send(text)
```

And I want to return the id of new message.

Answer (score 0):

**Message Docs**:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message

- `User.send` returns an object of `Message` type which has an id field.
- You can simply use
  `message.id` or `message.webhook_id` if message comes from webhook.

```py
async def send_message(user_id, text):
    user = self.client.get_user(user_id)
    message = await user.send(text)
    return message.id
```

Comment: anyways the reasoning holds for your new question as well.

Comment: Please, can you help me also?) I am trying to edit message. I do `await message.edit(content="changed!")`. But how can I edit the file? I sent it by `file = discord.File("video.mp4", filename="video.mp4")                                               await message.author.send("test", file=file)`.

Comment: looks like the feature is not available.

Comment: But I must do it:( And don't you know anyways to do it?

Comment: They just said the feature is not available, meaning they *don't* know how to do it because it's *impossible*. You can look at the [`Message.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.edit) documentation to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

add this at the end. It will send the `message.id` at the channel.

```py
await message.channel.send(message.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending any message to a [`Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) object returns the [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) object that was sent.

This means you can simply get the [`id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.id) attribute in your code, like this:

```py
async def send_message(user_id, text):
    user = self.client.get_user(user_id)
    message = await user.send(text)
    return message.id
```